# Wordpress action hook not firing (wpforms)

Tags: wordpress, action-hook

Ended up on a project with a Wordpress site.  I am trying to post data from a form made with WPforms to an external API.  Not a wordpress guy, but I read that I can hook into to action from other plugins by writing my own plugin.  Here is my plugin,

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: name
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: plugin to post user data from wp form
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: John
 * Author URI: http://www.mywebsite.com
 */

function register_lsf_mobile_user( $fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {
  $api_url =  "https://lsf-development.firebaseapp.com";

  $body = array(
    'email' => $fields[1]['value'],
    'password' => $fields[1]['value']
  );

  $request = wp_remote_post( $api_url, array('body' => $body) );

  if (is_wp_error($request)) {
    $msg  = "There was an error trying to register a lsfMobile user.\n";
        $msg .= 'Error returned: ' . $error = $request->get_error_message() . "\n\n";
        $msg .= "The user below may need to be added to the CRM manually.\n";
        $msg .= $body['name'] . ' ' . $body['email'];

        wp_mail( get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' ), 'lsfMobile user registration error', $msg );
  }
}
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete_16522', 'register_lsf_mobile_user', 10, 4 );
```

After zipping, uploading/installing, and then activating the above custom plugin I try to test it by embedding my wp_form in a private page and entering and submitting data.  However, my action hook doesn't seem to be called.  I tried doing the echo " alert("...")

Comment: Can you try your code in active theme's functions.php file instead of creating a custom plugin?

Comment: Did you try with 'wpforms_process_complete' instead of giving the form_id and then checking the form_id inside the function ? Do you use the plugin WP PHP Console to debug your php code into the browser's console ?