# In WordPress, can I have a form and a payment submit at the same time?

Tags: wordpress, forms, square-connect, payment-processing

Apologies for not knowing the exact terms to describe what I want, but I am using a simple WordPress theme site, the included WPForms plugin, and am trying to take orders using Square as my payment processing.

The current system I'm using works:  I have a WPForm that gets the order information I need, they submit the form, then that redirects to a page where they click a link and arrive at the payment window on Square.

The problem is that I'm finding there's abandonment between the order form sending and the payment -- so I get orders in my Inbox, then have to wait and eventually track down whether they're wanting to pay.  I'd really love to have my order arrive ONLY if payment is completed.

I could do this most simply by reversing the process, requiring someone pay first, THEN redirect to the order page...but that's a bad customer experience and I think people are more invested in completing a purchase if they're already excited by "ordering" it.

So I'm hoping someone can tell me if there's a plugin or method such that the very same "Order now" button will send the order to me AND process (and complete) the payment.

If this is more complicated than I think, if it's a huge headache, I will opt for either leaving it as is and tracking down payment...or reverse and make them pay first.  But any help or suggestions, particularly for a Plugin that can do what I'm looking for, would be great.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to purchase the Pro version of WPForms then it easily integrates with Stripe to collect payment at the same time that your Form is submitted.
https://wpforms.com/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe/

PayPal and Authorize.Net are other options that integrate with WPForms.

These other questions may be relevant as well:
[Wordpress action hook not firing (wpforms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583648/wordpress-action-hook-not-firing-wpforms)
[Wordpress Help (WPForms + PayPal Workflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914259/wordpress-help-wpforms-paypal-workflow)